# How do I read a uint from a pointer with Marshalling?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a native method which needs a pointer to write out a dword (uint).

Now I need to get the actual uint value from the (Int)pointer, but the Marshal class only has handy methods for reading (signed) integers.

How do I get the uint value from the pointer?

I've searched the questions (and Google), but couldn't really find what I needed.

Sample (not working) code:

```
IntPtr pdwSetting = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint)));

        try
        {
            // I'm trying to read the screen contrast here
            NativeMethods.JidaVgaGetContrast(_handleJida, pdwSetting);
            // this is not what I want, but close
            var contrast = Marshal.ReadInt32(pdwSetting);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pdwSetting);
        }
```

The return value from the native function is a dword between 0 and 255 with 255 being full contrast.

Comment: Can you please provide your sample code for our reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on whether you may use usafe code you can even do:

```
static unsafe void Method()
{
    IntPtr pdwSetting = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint)));

    try
    {
        NativeMethods.JidaVgaGetContrast(_handleJida, pdwSetting);
        var contrast = *(uint*)pdwSetting;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pdwSetting);
    }
}
```

Note, that a C++ function pointer like

```
void (*GetContrastPointer)(HANDLE handle, unsigned int* setting);
```

can be marshaled as

```
[DllImport("*.dll")]
void GetContrast(IntPtr handle, IntPtr setting); // most probably what you did
```

but also as

```
[DllImport("*.dll")]
void GetContrast(IntPtr handle, ref uint setting);
```

which lets you write code like

```
uint contrast = 0; // or some other invalid value
NativeMethods.JidaVgaGetContrast(_handleJida, ref contrast);
```

which is superior in both performance and readability.

Comment: I had totally forgotten about ref, how foolish of me. That's what I ended up with, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply cast it to `uint`:

```
uint contrast = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(pdwSetting);
```

For example:

```
int i = -1;
uint j = (uint)i;
Console.WriteLine(j);
```

outputs `4294967295`.

Comment: But positive values would have the same value and this is wrong, because the initial int readout is wrong.

Comment: No, the code above does what you want. You are a little confused here. This code behaves in exactly the same way as the unsafe code in the answer you accepted.

Comment: Okay, I thought that a value like 101 would be 5 when read as a uint and -1 when read with ReadInt32 and that converting -1 would give the high value you wrote down instead of the 5 I was looking for.

In a way, I thought that it would falsely read the high order bit as a sign but.

Comment: @Davio It does read the high order bit as the sign bit. But the high order bit for 0 is not set. The `(uint)` cast just re-interprets the bit pattern as a `uint`. Anyway, using an overload that takes `ref uint`, as per your accepted answer, is the best way to solve your problem. But the `(unit)` cast is the idiomatic way to do precisely what you ask in your question. So, I think I answered the direct question that you asked, but you accepted answer is the right solution for your underlying problem. Often that's a subtle difference!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Marshal.PtrToStructure overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx) that takes an IntPtr and a type and pass in typeof(uint) - that ought to work!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This seems to work, although I'm not sure, because currently the native method will always return 0 due to hardware limitations. Once I'm able to test it, I will post back.

Comment: @Davio - What hardware limitations?

Comment: @Ramhound I believe he means his native library is always returning 0 at this time (due to some limitation) - so he has no way of testing his library with values larger than int.MaxValue. Am I correct?

Comment: @ananthonline You are correct. One of the wires is soldered in a way that the current contrast is not set correctly, so it will always return 0.