# C# Marshaling Unsigned Char Return Value from C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, unsigned-char

I am importing functions from a C++ DLL into a C# application.  I am able to import and some of the functions but not others.  The C++ DLL came with a C++ project that shows how to use it from C++.  I want to replicate this in C# but I'm having trouble with the marshalling.  Here is the C++:

Header File Declarations:

```
unsigned long __stdcall mfcs_initialisation(unsigned short serial);
unsigned long __stdcall mfcsez_initialisation(unsigned short serial);   
unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_close(unsigned long handle);
unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_set_purge_on(unsigned long int handle);
unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_set_purge_off(unsigned long int handle);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_get_purge(unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char * c);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_get_status(
    unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char * c);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_read_chan(
    unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char canal,
    float * pressure,
    unsigned short * chrono);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_data_chan(
    unsigned long int  handle,
    unsigned char canal,
    unsigned char * unite,
    unsigned short * max,
    unsigned short * zero,
    unsigned short * mesure,
    unsigned short * chrono);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_get_serial(unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned short * us);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_set_auto(
    unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char canal,
    float pcons);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_set_alpha(
    unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char canal,
    unsigned char alpha);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_set_manual(
    unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char canal,
    float pcons);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_set_zero(
    unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned char canal,
    unsigned short zero);

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_detect(unsigned short table[256]);
unsigned char __stdcall mfcsez_detect(unsigned short table[256]);
```

C++ Code:

```
/* Define functions prototype */
typedef unsigned long(__stdcall *init)(int);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *purgeOn)(unsigned long handle);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *purgeOff)(unsigned long handle);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *serial)(unsigned long handle, unsigned short *serial);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *close)(unsigned long handle);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *setAuto)(unsigned long int handle, unsigned 
char canal, float pcons);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *readChannel)(unsigned long handle, unsigned 
char chan, float * pressure, unsigned short * chrono);
typedef unsigned char(__stdcall *setAlpha)(unsigned long int handle, unsigned 
char canal, unsigned char alpha);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* System settings variable definition */
float start_pressure = 70;         //Pressure set (mbar) at the beginning
float target_pressure = 100;        //Maximal pressure setpoint (mbar)
unsigned char pressureChannel = 1; //Selected channel (0 for all channels or put the channel number you would like to control)
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL=NULL;          // Define dll handler

/* Load DLL into memory */
hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mfcs_c.dll"));

/* Declare pointers on dll functions */
init dll_init;
purgeOn dll_purgeOn;
purgeOff dll_purgeOff;
serial dll_serial;
close dll_close;
setAuto dll_setAuto;
readChannel dll_readChannel;
setAlpha dll_setAlpha;

/* Link dll pointers with functions prototype */
dll_init = (init)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcsez_initialisation");
dll_serial = (serial)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_get_serial");
dll_purgeOn = (purgeOn)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_set_purge_on");
dll_purgeOff = (purgeOff)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_set_purge_off");
dll_close = (close)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_close");
dll_setAuto = (setAuto)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_set_auto");
dll_readChannel = (readChannel)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_read_chan");
dll_setAlpha = (setAlpha)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_set_alpha");

/* Define variables used for MFCS device */
unsigned long mfcsHandle;
unsigned short mySerial;
float read_pressure;
unsigned short chrono;
int loop_index;


if (hGetProcIDDLL != NULL) {        // If dll loaded
    std::cout << "mfcs_c.dll is loaded" << std::endl;

    /* Initialize device */
    if (dll_init != NULL) {         // Check if function was properly linked to the dll file
        /* Initialize the first MFCS in Windows enumeration list */
        mfcsHandle = dll_init(0);
        /* After the initialization we need to add a delay of 500ms to make sure that the USB communication is properly established */
        Sleep(500);
        std::cout << "MFCS initialized" << std::endl;
    }

    /* Read device serial number */
    if (dll_serial != NULL) {
        /*Get the serial number of the MFCS*/
        dll_serial(mfcsHandle, &mySerial);
        std::cout << "MFCS SN: " << mySerial << std::endl;
    }

    /* Set pressure regulation servitude coefficient */
    if (dll_setAlpha != NULL) {
        dll_setAlpha(mfcsHandle ,pressureChannel, 4);       // Default value (just after power on) is 0 
    }                                                       // Alpha value has to be grather than 0 in order to regulate pressure

    /* Change and read pressure every second until reaching 'target_pressure' value */
    for (loop_index = int(start_pressure); loop_index<target_pressure; loop_index++){
        dll_setAuto(mfcsHandle,pressureChannel,float(loop_index));               // Set required output pressure value         
        Sleep(1000);                                                             // Wait 1 s
        dll_readChannel(mfcsHandle, pressureChannel, &read_pressure, &chrono);   // Get the pressure value on the specified channel
        std::cout << "Set pressure at: " << loop_index << "mbar" << "; Read pressure: " << read_pressure
            << "mbar" << std::endl;                                              // Display pressure setpoint and channel pressure value
    }

    /* Close MFCS session */
    if (dll_close != NULL) {
        dll_close(mfcsHandle);
        std::cout << "MFCS closed" << std::endl;
    }
}

/* Release the DLL */
FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);
std::cout << "mfcs_c.dll unloaded" << std::endl;

/* Exit application */
system("PAUSE");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Basically I have tried many permutations of importing the functions and any of the ones that contain either unsigned chars or pointers I can't figure out how to map.

HUGE THANKS TO DAVID FOR PUSHING ME TO BE MORE USEFUL FROM MY END.

NOTE: An example of what would help me is clear instructions based on the C++ code above for pulling in the mfcs_get_serial(unsigned long int handle,
    unsigned short * serial) into C#.

Comment: the first version, the one with `byte` as the return value type, should be correct. how is `mySerial` initialized?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11829072/1132334)

Comment: Are you sure that your `unsigned long int`  in that flavor of C++ is 64 bit?  It could be a 32 bit, in which case you want to marshall in C# with a `uint`

Comment: dlatikay - I wasn't initializing mySerial.  I just declared it "ushort mySerial".  I tried initializing to zero after seeing your comment but it still blows up with the same error.

Comment: Tim - I switched from ulong to unit (see below) but it still blows up with the same error.

Comment: uint mfcsHandle;
        ushort mySerial=0;

        #region DLL Imports from Fluigent 64 bit SDK DLL
        
       [DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        protected static extern uint mfcsez_initialisation(ushort serial_number);

        [DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern byte mfcs_get_serial(uint handle, ref ushort us);

Answer (score 0):

**Note that this answer was written for the original version of the question before it was edited into a different question. Rather than risk an edit war I am leaving this as is.**

In C++ on Windows `long` is a 32 bit type. So

```
unsigned long __stdcall mfcs_initialisation(unsigned short serial);
```

should be

```
[DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern uint mfcs_initialisation(ushort serial);
```

The other function is harder to translate given the information provided. The second argument could be either a single value, or an array. The former is more likely. So the translation should be

```
[DllImport("mfcs_c_64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern byte mfcs_get_serial(uint handle, out ushort us);
```

Comment: David - thank you for your answer!  I changed the ulong's to uint's and tried changing the footprint of the import as you suggest to "out" rather than "ref" and I get the same thing.  If I use return type byte I get an exception from the DLL that shuts down the application - try/catch doesn't catch it.  If I use byte[] I get an exception that the try/catch catches.  It seems like it's got to be the return type marshalling.  When I call functions from the DLL with a return type of ulong (uint), the calls work perfectly.  Anything with a return type of unsigned char from the DLL blows up.

Comment: I'm just going on what I can see in the question. No doubt there is something important  that you haven't shared yet. The answer is accurate given the information. You'd see that if you made a minimal test bed. Of course, I did have to make one assumption, which I explained. You didn't confirm that my assumption was correct. As it stands, unless you put some more effort in, this is as much help as you can get for the question asked.

Comment: As an example, you claim the return type is `unsigned char`. That's a little surprising. Can you double check that it isn't `unsigned char*`.

Comment: David - apologies if I haven't provided enough info!  I'm doing my best.  Here is the declaration copied from the header file for the function:

Comment: David - Apologies!  I'm doing my best.  Here is the declaration copied from the header file:  

unsigned char __stdcall mfcs_get_serial(
  unsigned long int handle,
  unsigned short * us);

Wouldn't that be unsigned char rather than unsigned char*?  My CPP is rusty.

Comment: The code in my answer matches that. If my. Assumption on the second argument is correct. Once again you didn't address that. You aren't going to. Make progress like this. You need to understand more. We can't debug your program from here. There is more going on than we can see. Over and out.

Comment: I just understood what you were asking.  Sorry.  I am going back and forth working on things in the lab.  I am not trying to offend you!  It's a crazy day.  The second argument is NOT an array.  It is a serial number for the device.  When I use the software that came with the device it should be 1355.  A number not an array.

Comment: Here is the C++ code that uses the DLL from vendor example:

 init dll_init;
 serial dll_serial;

 /* Link dll pointers with functions prototype */
 dll_init = (init)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcsez_initialisation");
 dll_serial = (serial)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "mfcs_get_serial");

 unsigned long mfcsHandle;
 unsigned short mySerial;

 mfcsHandle = dll_init(0);
 Sleep(500);
 dll_serial(mfcsHandle, &mySerial);

Comment: Once again, the code in the answer is correct given the info in the question. Problem is elsewhere. And once again, you'd know that was true if you built a simple test bed dll.

Comment: I think the primary problem, David, is that the unmanaged DLL I am trying use was written by the French.  (LOL)  You have helped me a lot and I have a clear idea of what information may be needed to get to the bottom of it.  Also, I was never challenging what you sent was wrong!  I was just reporting back quick results as I ran around like a madman.  I am going to repost to the main question.  I'll give it a dig anyway.

Comment: The point is that this is not a debugging service. I answered the question you asked. That's it. If you can't solve your problem yet, that's another matter. As you know by now, with your test bed program, the code here matches that in the question. Probably better if you deleted the question since it can't help anybody else.

Comment: My question has not been answered.  The mapping into C# is wrong.  Period.  If you are going to be unpleasant just stop looking at this thread.  I've been polite and thankful for your attempt to help me.  I believe once I get this working it will be helpful as I have googled for 2 days and can not find a solution.  Have a good one dude.

Comment: The mapping is correct. As you found out in your test bed dll. Actually, you probably didn't write one. Can't imagine why not. As, please don't change the question. I reverted your edit that asked a different question.

Comment: You are wrong and now being childish.   Did you even read the edit?  Your actually blocking someone from helping me and further mocking me.  Can you not just go away?  I am here to get help.  I'm not sure what you mean by creating a test bed dll so either explain that or go away.